# Windows Forms custom control: focus and cursor keys without UIPermissionWindow.AllWindows

Tags: winforms, permissions, keyboard, custom-controls, focus

I want to write a custom control (a text editor) for Windows Forms, which should include the following functionality:

- Gets the keyboard focus, when you click on it with the mouse
- Sees all keyboard input (including cursor keys), when it has the focus,
- Can run in a semi-trusted environment, with `UIPermissionWindow.SafeTopLevelWindows` (i.e. it shouldn't require `UIPermissionWindow.AllWindows`)

Is there any example of doing this?

Some of the methods which I might want to use, like `Control.Focus()` and `Control.InInputKey()`, require `UIPermissionWindow.AllWindows`.

Is there any other way to get/implement the functionality, without using these methods?

The built-in TextBox control has this functionality (gets the focus and handles cursor keys).

Comment: can't you simply inherit from TextBox and add the other functionalities you need?

Comment: @vulkanino - TextBox paints itself; and overriding OnPaint isn't enough to conceal that: I think it's doing some unmanaged painting as well.

Comment: Control.CreateHandle() has the demand as well.  Don't worry about it.

Comment: @Hans Passant - I don't know what Control.CreateHandle() does, but I don't call it (or at least, not explicitly). I'm "worrying about it" because I find that if I invoke any method which requires UIPermissionWindow.AllWindows then this causes an exception if I use the control in an application which is running in the 'Internet' (i.e. semi-trusted) security zone. The TextBox control is OK though (doesn't throw security exceptions when it's run in the Internet zone); and I don't think I'm trying to do anything (with focus and arrow keys) that the TextBox isn't doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Public Class UserControl1
    Inherits TextBox

    Private Sub UserControl1_GotFocus(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.GotFocus

    End Sub

    Private Sub UserControl1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
        Debug.WriteLine("downed")
        Debug.WriteLine(e.KeyValue)
        Debug.WriteLine(e.KeyCode)

    End Sub

    Private Sub UserControl1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyPress
        Debug.WriteLine("pressed")
        Debug.WriteLine(e.KeyChar)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: The GotFocus event is fired when it gets the focus, but doesn't cause the focus. To get the focus on a mouse click, I might have wanted to invoke this.Focus() in the MouseDown event handler (but can't because Focus() requires UIPermissionWindow.AllWindows).

Comment: The KeyDown event handler doesn't get various keys, including the Return and Arrow keys, because they are 'preprocessed' unless IsInputKey retrns true (and overriding IsInputKey requires UIPermissionWindow.AllWindows).

Comment: Your event handlers work when you inherit from TextBox instead of inhering from Control; I guess that TextBox is doing the necessary Focus() and IsInputKey() internally. I don't know how to derive from TextBox though: because TextBox paints itself, and overriding OnPaint isn't enough to override/conceal TextBox's painting (I think TextBox is doing some unmanaged painting as well). I'd like to have/implement the same focus and arrow key behaviour as TextBox, but I don't see how. Note that TextBox is allowed to run even in a `UIPermissionWindow.SafeTopLevelWindows` environment.

Comment: why would you override OnPaint?

Comment: please try my code. if you want to override OnPaint then do:

 Sub New()

        InitializeComponent()

        SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, True)
 End Sub

 Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs)
'...
    End Sub

Comment: I want to override OnPaint because I'm developing a custom control, and I want to do my own painting: the control displays multiple lines, multiple fonts, rectangles, etc.

Comment: @vulkanino "please try my code" - It works, if the base.Text is an empty string (if the TextBox.Text contains text, then that text is painted even though I override OnPaint and don't call Base.OnPaint ... I think it's being called by unmanaged code). The problem (the only problem) I see now is that the base TextBox is painting its insertion caret (that blinking vertical line) whenever it has the focus.

Comment: Ok my plan is: (1) in a high-trust environment, derive from Control; (2) else in a low-trust environment, derive from TextBox, if there's a toolbar under which I can hide the caret; (3) else in a low-trust environment without a toolbar under which to hide the caret, derive from Control and have a hidden TextBox as a member (then I can at least get all the keystrokes from the hidden text box while the text box has the focus; although a mouse click on the control won't set the focus).

Comment: *You don't read Chris.*

Call this method in your derived class constructor: SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, True)

Your OnPaint will be called and you'll decide what to write in the control, with your own brushes and everything.

Comment: I *am* calling `SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true)`. If I don't call it, then my OnPaint is never called at all. However even though I set `ControlStyles.UserPaint`, even though my `OnPaint` is called, even though I can paint any/everything I like, and even though my `OnPaint` does *not* invoke `base.OnPaint`, nevertheless the base TextBox is *still doing some painting of its own*: of any text which it contains, and its caret is being painted too. I guess that painting is being done by unmanaged code (perhaps a Win32 edit control), which I can't override/ignore in the subclass.